# Obj-c *** -[CFString copyWithZone:]: message sent to deallocated instance

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, crash, cfstring

Here is the complete error in debugger :

```
2012-11-11 17:57:34.534 Killer[13745:707] *** -[CFString copyWithZone:]: message sent to     deallocated instance 0xee57540
2012-11-11 18:01:59.231 Killer[13745:707] *** -[CFString class]: message sent to deallocated instance 0xee57540
(lldb)
```

Programming with Obj C and Cocos 2d v1.0.1, here is the crashing line

```
player.zombieImage = [playersPicturesZombies objectAtIndex:idx];
```

The strange thing is that i am doing the potential crashing operation 10 times before it crashes, is this linked to a memory problem then ? Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Yes, that's a memory problem. Are you using ARC? If so, do you have a strong reference to zombieImage? If not, are you retaining it?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, i have the setting Automatic Reference Counting set to NO in my project. But as i am discovering that it exists, i am now wondering whether i should use it :) what do you mean by strong reference ? My zombieImage is a member of my instance player, the latter being also a member of my current class. So yes, this is supposed to be strong right ? :)

Comment: Would you advise using ARC ?

Comment: Here is zombieImage declaration : @property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *zombieImage;

Comment: I don't understand where and why i need to retain a NSString member, could you please explain ? Thanks a lot

Comment: 'Where': need to see the code to see where you need to send it a retain message. 'Why': Sending it retain will give you ownership so it will stick around until you send it a release.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering, let me explain it a little bit more please : i have global variable playersPicturesZombies initialized like this : <br/>`playersPicturesZombies = [[NSMutableArray alloc ] initWithCapacity:playersNames.count];` then i add objects in it with <br/>`for (NSString * name in playersNames){
        [playersPictures addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",name,defaultImageExtension] ];}`